# get_the_title() of some post and work with it's value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a standart loop with:

```
    <article class="somepost">  
       <?php       $a = get_the_title();   echo $a; ?>  
    </article>
```

How I get value of some post's title, when I click on some article (class="somepost")

```
     $('.somempost').click(function(){ ??? });
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would set the title to the articles data attribute:

```
<?php $a = get_the_title(); ?>
<article class="somepost" data-title="<?php echo $a; ?>">
    <?php echo $a; ?>
</article>
```

Then in your jQuery, set the title to a variable like so:

```
$('.somepost').click(function(){
    var the_title = $(this).data('title');
});
```